# MYSQL SELECT Join on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this Table in my MySql database:

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

The `parent_id` conform to the `category_id` of the table(recursive):

```
category_id title   parent_id
1           David   0
2           Lenny   1
3           Tom     1
4           John    3
5           Donald  4
6           Kelly   2
```

I want to select on the table but to get the parent_id as the title, It's possible to do Join SELECT like this? It's will not create any slow issue?

Comment: You should be able to do that the same way as doing it with 2 different tables just use custom names for tables to know what to reference in the select e.g.
SELECT a.title FROM Category A JOIN Category B on A.category_id = B.parent.Id. There shouldn't be any slowness issue, but you might want to use indexes (primary key for category_id and foreign key for parent_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join a table to itself. Here's a query you could use; you may need to modify it slightly to get the exact columns you want.

```
select
  child.title `child`,
  parent.title `parent`
from
       Category `child`
  join Category `parent` on `child`.parent_id = `parent`.category_id
;
```

That query will return this result:

```
child   parent
--------------
Lenny   David
Tom     David
John    Tom
Donald  John
Kelly   Lenny
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle you can play around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a254cb/3

Edit: Here's a version with a left join if you care about parentless David: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a254cb/4

Edit: And no, for a small table with a simple join like this, there is no performance concern.

Comment: You loose the row with id=1. Use LEFT join and COALESCE().

Comment: OP didn't specify if David matters, given that he has no parents. But yes, a left join would handle that. Updated answer to include a left join example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a254cb/4). The coalesce can be added if desired to have MySQL display a non-null value like "No parent".

Comment: *OP didn't specify if David matters, given that he has no parents* Primarily he had not specified that root row(s) must be skipped.

Comment: @Jon Thank, the second option is what I need because I want to get all data